# Vim - Is there a way to 'overlap' pages? (Getting visually lost when switching pages with Ctrl+f/b)

Tags: vim

When I press `Ctrl-f` or `Ctrl-b`, it takes a few seconds for me to read some
text to figure out where I am in the file. Is there some way I can make myself
not get lost so easily?

For example, is it possible to change `Ctrl-f` or `Ctrl-b` so that they move
some lines less than a page? If this is not possible, then is there a way to
make Vim move line-by-line, quickly, but not so quickly that you can't see the
text scroll up/down?

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> will scroll up half a page.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> will scroll down half a page.

You may change this behaviour by setting `scroll` to the number of lines you wish these commands to scroll. For example:

<kbd>Esc</kbd>`:set scroll=1`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Or, in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set scroll=1
```